# proof for greedy approach to http://www.spoj.com/problems/SAM/

Tags: algorithm

I was solving this problem : http://www.spoj.com/status/SAM,iiit/ 
I somehow arrived at the solution but I still can't prove it mathematically.
What the problem statement:

```
There are 'n' toys (1<=n<=10^5) on a shelf.A child is on the floor.He demands toys in
a sequence to play with , specified by 'p' (1<=p<=5*10^5).His mother gives him a toy
from the shelf if the child demanded a toy which is not on floor.At a time only
'k'(1<=k<=n) toys can be there on floor.So mother when giving toy from shelf can pick a
toy from floor and put it back to shelf if she wants.
So we have to minimize total number of times mother picks toys from shelf.
```

My solution:
(a)Variable and functions:

```
Keep a set of toys on floor and a variable ans(initially 0),which stores the answer.
Also next[],next[i] tells when will toy number 'i' come next in the demand sequence,
ie. index of its next occurrence in demand sequence.
update next[x] updates next[x] to store the next index of its occurrence in  demand 
sequence.If there is no further occurrence next[x]=MAX_INTEGER;
```

(b) Algorithm

```
Following are the cases:
1.If child demands a 'x' toy from shelf:
  increment ans
  If there are less than k elements then:
       add the element to the set
       update next[x]
  If there are k elements:
      remove the element from set whose value of next[] is largest
      add element 'x' to set 
      update next[x]
2.If child demands toy from floor say toy 'x':
  update next[x]
ans is the final answer.
```

Now I can't prove why this greedy type approach  is mathematically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact a caching problem - the floor is the cache, and the self is the main memory.

The algorithm you gave is optimal, since it is just the [clairvoyant algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#The_theoretically_optimal_page_replacement_algorithm). It is a classic algorithm and you can find it on a lot of Operating System resources.

There are several online too, e.g., [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~bvr/psfiles/paging.pdf) and [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2009/cmsc451/lectures/Lec05b-optcache.pdf).